# Interpreting Correlogram

Tags: time-series, correlation

I am wondering if anyone has any ideas as to how to interpret the following correlogram?

[image]
Or in general, what is the best way to treat/interpret a correlogram that exhibits a curve

[image]

Comment: Hint: When patterns in correlograms are simple, the plot of the time series itself often tells you what is going on. Here it seems that you have detrended, so plot the residuals versus time.

Comment: @NickCox does simple mean that we are seeing a pattern in the correlogram? I've updated the plot of res vs time, I'm still not sure how to interpret these results, I was hoping that the detrended series would indicate what type of model I should use

Comment: You changed your example while I was commenting. What you are showing me is not nearly so simple as the graph you first showed. How can you show lags up to 800 if time only goes up to 70?

Comment: @NickCox Sorry about chaging it, I just thought to check later lags. I've fixed the discrepancy with the times, sorry my mistake for not plotting it properly

Comment: Clearly you're allowed to change your question; I was just flagging that my first comment did not apply with as much force. I see evident for periodicity. There should be some substantive interpretation. As everything is left anonymous, I can't but guess. For example, if time is in units of 15 min, is there a daily periodicity?

Comment: @NickCox These are daily observations, when you say periodicity is that the same as seasonality?

Comment: You can have a periodicity that is nothing to do with seasonality. The cycle of day and night is one example. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodicity is one of many starts.